# Why are same-drive relative-path symlinks created with non-Admin WSL under a drvfs mountpoint inaccessible in Windows?

Tags: windows, ntfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, symbolic-link, wsl2

When I try to use the same-drive, relative-path NTFS symlink I created with WSL under a Windows drive / drvfs mountpoint on the Windows side, I get error that it is inaccessible. The symlink has the icon of a folder/directory without the "link icon" at its corner.

However, if the symlink were created in an WSL shell started in an Administrator PowerShell (Windows Terminal), it would work fine on the Windows side as well. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out by default when WSL is not started as Admin, it creates "WSL symlink" (which is not usable on the Windows side except in msys2 or so) even when the target is relative path and on the same drive as the link.

Because the target path was relative, it was recognizable on Windows (even when the link was not usable) and therefore, instead of the "whitepaper" file icon, a folder / directory icon was used for the link.

Apparently WSL is not made (at the very least, no longer as of Windows 11 21H2, if ever) an privilege exception / escalation with regards to NTFS symlink. However, there has long been a way to generally allow NTFS symlink to be created by non-Admin users, namely [Developer Mode](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/):

[image]

(Setting location on Windows 11 21H2)

After enabling the mode, symlinks created with non-Admin WSL for the particular case (Windows drive + same drive + relative path) would be proper NTFS ones.

Comment: There's a more specific configuration item for symlink creation under `secpol.msc` (under Privileges), in case someone doesn't want to activate everything that Developer Mode provides.